# facebook user authentication php

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Codeignitor .

I want to post to facebook through my application.

the problem is it always returns you are not logged in.

here what i tried ..

```
function postTofb()
{


require_once("pocket/fb/facebook.php");
        $fbconfig = array();
        $fbconfig['appId'] = 'app_id';
        $fbconfig['secret'] = 'app_secret';
        $fbconfig['baseurl']    = "site_name";

                $facebook = new Facebook($fbconfig);
        $user = $facebook->getUser();


               if($user)
           {
            try {

                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $ID = $user_profile['id'];
            echo $ID;

                 } 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
        {

        echo $e;

             }


        }
        else
        {

        //else starts

            $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'=> 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
                'redirect_uri'=>$fbconfig['baseurl']
            )
        );
    $data["status"] = FALSE;
    $data["url"] = $loginUrl;
    echo json_encode($data);
    //else ends
        }
    }
```

now i am calling the function through ajax...but it always response with FALSE...i mean the else part.

here what i am getting

```
{"status":false,"url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/dialog\/oauth?client_id=281255791959236&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.MY_SITE_NAME.com%2F&state=3d19a96f48022344222f518609f30537&scope=email%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_hometown"}
```

looks like i missed some points...please help me..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Offline access is no longer supported by facebook, only thing you can do is generate a token with max 60 days.

Comment: Well first try without the offline access ok?

Comment: yeah..how can i generate a token ?

Comment: i know that...the problem is still `getUser` returns `0`...also how can i use the accessTocken ?

Comment: Here is a link this will help you out [link](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was associated with LoginUrl

I removed some of the permission parameters and it worked.

`loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope")=>"publish_stream");`

Thank you.